# Scalable server configuration for dynamic growing social site

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, load-balancing, cache, memcache

My team is writing (social) website, witch should in theory grow up very fast. 
My task is to attempt to define the hardware requirements for such a page (for investors).
Technology in which we create a page is PHP + MySQL. For some time I read about load balancers, squid, haproxy etc...
Can anyone recommend a good source of knowledge where I could learn more about the possible configurations of servers and hardware combinations?

Comment: I would say that books are good sources for knowledge. Or the Internet.

Comment: Sounds like you are way out of your depth - you want other people to provide you an answer which might require weeks of information gathering in around 10 lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These titles are a good starting point:

[Scalable Internet Architectures](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/067232699X)

[Web Operations: Keeping the Data On Time](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449377440)

Make sure you have a test or staging environment where you can try out new configurations before you push things to prod.

Cheers